# Can't read text in text to speech tool for a protected pdf

Tags: pdf, text-to-speech, copy-protection, tts

I am using natural reader for reading purpose, recently unlocked my protected pdf file from Splitpdf online password remover software. Extracted pdf doesn't have the language I expected.

Attached picture below, observe the search result of google.
[image].

Natural reader image:
[image]

In natural reader it was coated with special characters.

Is there any solution to the problem?

Comment: It could be that the PDF contains both an *image* of the words and OCR of the *text* in the words. Sometimes, OCR fails badly. If you *copy* the highlighted text, and paste into a text reader, such as Notepad, Notepad++ or Kate, how does it appear there? Perhaps, add a screenshot of that to the question.

Comment: Same as the above one @DrMoishePippik

Comment: Sounds like a case where OCR has failed horribly not much you can do in a case like that

Comment: @Ramhound, I had attached new image, check that one, It was coated with special characters

Comment: "recently unlocked my protected pdf file from Splitpdf online password remover software" - you removed the protection, which resulted in corruption of the content of your file. That's the purpose of protection of pdf files. If you've a legitimate interest, you might ask the author of the file for an unprotected copy.

Comment: Just buy the ebook called `A TEXTBOOK OF ISC BIOLOGY for Class -XII
by Sarita Aggarwal` at Google Books for 20 euros instead of trying to steal it....

Comment: @Gantendo, I have legit copy, natural reader is not able to read it, is there any another way to use it?